# How to get the Window Class Name and Id from HWND?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get the Window Class Name and Id from  HWND?

I searched but found the opposite is more popular.

Any thoughts?!?!?

Answer (score 8):

Answers by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246663/how-to-get-the-window-class-name-and-id-from-hwnd/3246704#3246704) and [Arthur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246663/how-to-get-the-window-class-name-and-id-from-hwnd/3246701#3246701) show how to get the class name. With 'Id' perhaps you mean the window identifier for child windows;

```
GetWindowLong(HWnd, GWL_ID)
```

Comment: supersede version: `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_ID);`

Answer (score 6):

GetClassName: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(v=VS.85).aspx

What do you mean with Id?

Comment: God, you beat me with eight seconds!

Comment: Thanks

I heard there is an id that identifies specific window, if the application has more than one instance of the class.

Comment: Mohammad, the *handle* identifies a specific window. You already have that.

Comment: But how can I get the class name length to call the GetClassName properly? I mean, I need to allocate buffer first!

Comment: @Zato: Welcome to C! WNDCLASS tells you, that a classname is max. 256 char long.

Answer (score 4):

[GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(VS.85).aspx) is exactly what you're looking for.